# SQL Database not connected in NodeJS it showing an error during connection

Tags: sql, node.js, xampp

```
config.js
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
  },
};

db.js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  process.env.DB_USER,
  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql",
  }
);

module.exports = sequelize;

.env
DB_USER='root',
DB_PASSWORD=null,
DB_DATABASE='cf',
DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
```

it show the error to connect SQL database in XAMPP given below:

> click-fit@1.0.0 migrate:undo
> sequelize-cli db:migrate:undo

Sequelize CLI [Node: 21.2.0, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.35.1]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.js".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Access denied for user ''root','@'localhost' (using password: YES`enter code here`